# HttpPost (Android ≤ 4.0) in Broadcast Receiver (AsyncTask?)

Tags: android, http-post, compatibility

I'm building an app that is passing variables to my server through an HttpPost. Everything was working well until I updated my Android 2.3 device to Android 4.0 yesterday. After the update the app that I'm working on crashes each time the HttpPost is run. I figured that since the same code was working in Android 2.3 the issue is that it's just not compatible with the updated system.

What is the best way that I can pass the same variables and still be compatible with Android 2.3 - 4.0? What is the best practice here? I'm fairly new to mobile development. How is my methodology?

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("MY URL");
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receiver", "BLAH"));
   try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   try {
    httpClient.execute(httpPost);
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

**Update**

Here's my LogCat

```
07-06 10:41:25.385: D/DroidGap(6856): DroidGap.onCreate()
07-06 10:42:09.205: I/dalvikvm(7330): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 10...
07-06 10:42:09.275: D/AndroidRuntime(7330): Shutting down VM
07-06 10:42:09.275: W/dalvikvm(7330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40acd210)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver tellatext.sms.app.SmsReceiver: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2229)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:134)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1119)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:441)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:243)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at tellatext.sms.app.SmsReceiver.onReceive(SmsReceiver.java:114)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2221)
07-06 10:42:09.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7330): ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your URL request in background process.

Here is sample code

```
new TestTask().execute();
```

and

```
public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("MY URL");
         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receiver", "BLAH"));
           try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
           try {
            httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
        return null;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Android 3.0 and Higher do not allow to send Network Request on main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're running your networking task on your main thread.

Run your networking task in an AsyncTask, so it won't block your UI thread. Never run blocking tasks in your UI thread. Here's a tutorial: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I have posted it 4 min ago! :) No need to post same answer again. If you think the answer is good just up vote it.

Comment: It's explained really well in the Android documentation for which I posted the link. Just read it thoroughly ;) AsyncTasks work on API level 3 and higher, which means they work on Android 1.5 and higher.

@MMohsinNaeem Just wanted to help out with a documentation reference and a further explanation and I didn't have enough rep to comment on your post until now - Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using Asynctask (as mentioned by other guys)
2. Are you using proxy server? normally if you connect to Internet through 3G, mobile operator set proxy server + port, automatically on your device. If you are using it, try to clear it and run your application again.